# Customizing a RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, ticks

I would like to customize the `RegionPlot` with the following:

1. Add text ticks to the `RegionPlot`
2. Change `1` to show as `a` or another text
3. Add a vertical `Red` line at such a tick location

Code:

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 < 2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {{1}, None}}]
```

Expected Outcome:

[image]

Comment: `RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 < 2}
 , {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}
 , FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {{{1, Style["a", 16, Red]}}, None}}
 , Frame -> True
 , Epilog -> {
   Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]
   , InfiniteLine[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}]
   }
 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The parametric of the `Ticks` is `{{x, label, {plen, mlen}, style}}`.
- we extend the tick to full size by using  `{plen, mlen}={1., 0.}`, that is, the positive directions is `1.` and the `negative directions` is `0.`

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 < 2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, 
    None}, {{{1, Style["a", Blue, 14], {1., 0.}, 
      Directive[Red, Thick]}}, None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 < 2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{-1, "mone"}, {-0.5, "mhalf"}, {0, "zero"}, {0.5, 
      "half"}, {1, "one"}}, 
    None}, {{{0, "zero"}, {0.5, "half"}, {1, "one", {1, 0}, 
      Directive[Red, Thick]}, {1.5, "onehalf"}}, None}}]
```

[image]