# Customizing a RegionPlot with ticks

Tags: regions

I would like to customize the RegionPlot with the following:
Remove thin frame, but remain the ticks and frame labels.

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 < 2, x^2 + y^2 > 2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 
  1.5}, FrameLabel -> {a, b}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {{1}, None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related to my another anweer. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/276186/72111

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 < 2, x^2 + y^2 > 2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 
  1.5}, FrameLabel -> {Style[a, Black, 14], Style[b, Black, 14]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, 
    None}, {{{1, Style["1", Blue, 14], {0.025, -0.025}, 
      Directive[Red, Thick]}}, None}}, FrameStyle -> White, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, looks perfect.

Comment: @ChinChingCHAN  You can up-vote the answer by  ▲ or accept the answer by √  on the left of the answer.

Comment: I just started using this website recently, so I am not familiar with the functions. Sorry.